# How to insert same value into many variables in C#?

Tags: c#, variables

I have many int variables, blueBallVelocityX1, blueBallVelocityX2, blueBallVelocityX3, blueBallVelocityX4, blueBallVelocityX5, blueBallVelocityX6, blueBallVelocityX7, blueBallVelocityX8, blueBallVelocityX9, blueBallVelocityX10, blueBallVelocityX11, blueBallVelocityX12, blueBallVelocityX13, blueBallVelocityX14, blueBallVelocityX15, blueBallVelocityX16, blueBallVelocityX17, blueBallVelocityX18, blueBallVelocityX19, blueBallVelocityX20  and blueBallVelocityY1 (1-20). I need to appoint all the variables with value 5. How do I do about it?

Comment: Your question is a riddle. Maybe it helps to see what you've tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should think about using collections, such as an [array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
const int VelocityLength = 20;
const int InitialVelocity = 5;

int[] blueBallVelocityX = new int[VelocityLength];
int[] blueBallVelocityY = new int[VelocityLength];

for (int i = 0; i < VelocityLength; i++)
{
    blueBallVelocityX[i] = blueBallVelocityY[i] = InitialVelocity;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
int[] blueBallVelocityX = Enumerable.Repeat(InitialVelocity, VelocityLength).ToArray();
```

Comment: I got an error Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type int. May I know what is wrong with it?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to access an element of an int type, rather than an int array

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for a multidimensional array:

```
int[,] blueBallVelocity = new int[2,20];
for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
        blueBallVelocity[x, y] = 5;
```

Or a single-dimensional array of `Point`s:

```
Point[] blueBallVelocity = new Point[20];
for (int i = 0; i < blueBallVelocity.Length; i++) 
    blueBallVelocity[i] = new Point(5, 5);
```

Comment: Or just use a [Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx)

Comment: I am not using multidimensional array. For both the blueBallVelocityX1(1-20) and blueBallVelocityY1(1-20), I want to set it value to 3.

Comment: @ElaineHarden - Yes, you are not using a multidimensional array. The question is *why*. Because as you describe your problem, using a multidimensional array would be a much better option than using a lot of very similar variables.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
blueBallVelocityX1 = 5;
blueBallVelocityX2 = 5;
// ...
blueBallVelocityX20 = 5;
```

What you should do is more like this

```
public class Ball
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public Point Location { get; set; }
    public Vector2D Velocity { get; set; }
}


var balls = new List<Ball>(20);
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    balls.Add(new Ball { Location = new Point(5, 5) });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two options

1. Put them into array instead of making many variables.
2. Use reflection if above point is impossible to achieve.

Comment: Is it really possible to set local variable value with reflection?

Answer (score 0):

```
  int blueBallVelocityX1 = 5;
  //...
  int blueBallVelocityX20 = 5;
```

Or if you're tired of writting so many lines, redefine blueBallVelocity to be an array instead:

```
  var blueBallVelocity = new int[20];
  for (var i = 0; i < blueBallVelocity.Length; i++) {
    blueBallVelocity[i] = 5;
  }
```